# I have 3 values (5, 4, 8) and I want to distribute them randomly between 10 cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have 10 cells A1:A10 and I have 3 values (5, 4, 8)

I want to distribute them randomly in A1:A10 so only 3 of 10 cells will be filled and the other 7 will be blank

How to make it?

for example:
[please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBymR.png)

[please see the other screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG8B6.png)

Comment: Pick a number between 1 and 10.  Pick another number between 1 and 10 (and keep doing so until it is not the first number).  Pick yet another number between 1 and 10 (and keep doing so until it is not the first number or the second number).  Put `5` into the row specified by the first number.  Put `4` into the row specified by the second number.  Put `8` into the row specified by the third number.

Comment: thank you for the reply, please see the screenshot that I posted to understand what I need

Comment: It's OK - I understood what you meant - my comment gives you a good way to do that.  (I guess I should have added as a step #1 - "delete current contents of rows 1 to 10 before doing anything".)  (And I guess my "Pick a number" should really have said "Pick a **random** number", but I thought that was obvious.)

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant but thanks a lot for attempting to help

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve this with regular Excel formulas and here is how you do it:

[image]

- `Column A`: Enter those three values you mentioned (5, 4, 8) and **other 7 cells with one empty space**.
- `Column B`: Fill out this formula `=RAND()`
- `Column C`: Fill out this fomrula `=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,RANK(B2,$B$2:$B$11))`

What this does is to return non-duplicate random list by the ranking.  And therefore, you have to have other 7 cells with an empty space.

Please also note that I have a header row so you may need to tweak the formula a little bit to fit your need.  Try and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to automate you can tie the following VBA to a command button.
I have included a link to how you can also randomize the array holding the numbers 4,5,8. Assumes you are running in a sheet called TargetSheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AssignNumbers()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim x As Long, i As Long
Dim Arr()

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("TargetSheet")
Set rng = ws.[A1:A10]

Arr = Array(4, 5, 8)  'You can randomize this array as follows (somewhat irrelevant as assignment is random): _
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShuffleArray.aspx

rng.ClearContents

For i = 0 To 2
    'Loop until we find an empty cell to place the value in
    Do
        x = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10)
        'Exit the loop as soon as we find a place to put the value
        If IsEmpty(rng.Cells(x, 1).Value) Then Exit Do
    Loop
    'Have found an empty cell - we can now set the value
    rng.Cells(x, 1) = arr(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, that worked :) but can you assist me a little further and make it automated so it can be changed each time I put a new data in the sheet making a button?

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for that. What i had done was add the following: 
    If IsEmpty(rng.Cells(x, 1).Value) Then
        rng.Cells(x, 1) = Arr(i)
    Else
       i = i - 1
    End If
Next i

Comment: That would work but my personal opinion is that modifying the loop variable is a dangerous habit to get into.  (It usually ends up being harder to maintain code that doesn't keep a `For` loop being a simple loop from `start value` to `end value`.)  So I would recommend avoiding that if you can.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a list (or array) of number from 1 to 10
2. Randomise the order of the list
3. Plot the numbers in the randomised order in A1:10*
4. Profit!

*Any numbers which arent 4, 5 or 8, can be translated to a blank cell

**Creating and randomising an array and printing it to A1:10**

```
Sub RunShuffle()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim MyArray(9) As Variant

    'Fill the array with numbers 1 to 10
    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        MyArray(i) = i + 1
    Next i

    'Randomise the order of the array
    ShuffleArrayInPlace MyArray

    'Print the randomised array to A1:10
    For j = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        Sheets(1).Cells(j + 1, "A").Value = MyArray(j)
        If MyArray(j) <> 4 And MyArray(j) <> 5 And MyArray(j) <> 8 Then
            Sheets(1).Cells(j + 1, "A").Value = ""
        End If
    Next j

End Sub

'This Sub shuffles the array given as input
Sub ShuffleArrayInPlace(InArray() As Variant)
    Dim n As Long
    Dim Temp As Variant
    Dim j As Long

    Randomize
    For n = LBound(InArray) To UBound(InArray)
        j = CLng(((UBound(InArray) - n) * Rnd) + n)
        If n <> j Then
            Temp = InArray(n)
            InArray(n) = InArray(j)
            InArray(j) = Temp
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

Source for randomisation code: [CPearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShuffleArray.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, theoretically your solution is going to work but I don't know how to randomize the order of the list nor how to plot the numbers, can u please help me explaining more?

Comment: Try the code I added. The only slightly difficult part, was to randomise the order of the array. I stole that from CPearson.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked :) but can you assist me a little further and make it refresh automatically so it can be changed each time I put a new data in the sheet?

and also how can I take a value from a cell instead of choosing 4, 5, 8?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "each time I put new data in the sheet". You could go to `Sheet1` (under Microsoft Excel Objects, in the VBA editor). And then put it in the WorkSheet_Change function. But be aware, that this will proc itself when it inserts the numbers, hence causing an infinite loop. Consider using `Application.EnableEvents = False` to prevent this (and set it to true after the code has run).

Comment: OK thanks a lot man :) :) I'm so sorry to ask so many questions but can u tell me how to start it from B5:B15 instead of A1:A10? I really appreciate your help

Comment: Change it to `Sheets(1).Cells(j + 15, "B").Value = MyArray(j)` and the same for the line that removes all non-wanted numbers.